# Javascript RegEx to check a certain number of Numeric characters in string regardless of other characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a field which the user will be entering a 9 digit numeric string.

**e.g.** 975367865

However some users will be entering the 9 digit numeric string with seperators such as "-" and "/".

**e.g.** 9753/67/865 OR 9753-67-865

I want to make sure that the user has entered a **minimum** of 9 numbers even if the user has added the "-" & "/" somewhere in the string.

Hope that makes sense.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: `\d` is pretty much all you need - http://jsfiddle.net/gLwxo78s/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just remove anything that is not a number to give a nice normalized form:

```
var number = input.replace(/[^\d]/g, "");

var ok = number.length == 9;
```

Comment: Use `\D`, `[^\d]` not.

Answer (score 0):

Match with a quantifier:

```
/^\d(?:\D*\d){8}$/
```

- `^$` are **Anchors** that asserts position at the start of end of the String. This asserts the entire match, but since you're only matching, you can leave them out!
- `\d` matches a digit.
- `\D*` skips ahead of any non-digits. Then a digit will be matched with `\d`.
- This group is then quantified: `(?: ){8}` To assert that the later alternation is matched eight times. Parted with the first match, this asserts that 9 digits are present in the match!

[View an online regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/dM4iS3/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
 (?=[\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9][\-\/]*[0-9]+[\-\/]*)(.*)
```

Though a rather long looking regex but works perfectly well for your case.
Have a look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/uR2aE4/3